# BigQuery Subtract Counts of Two Tables?

Tags: google-bigquery

In MySQL I can do `SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1) - (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2)` to get the difference in counts between two tables. When I try this in BigQuery, I get: `Subselect not allowed in SELECT clause`. How do I run a query like this in BigQuery?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**2019 update**:

The original question syntax is now supported with #standardSQL

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) c FROM `publicdata.samples.natality`) 
  - (SELECT COUNT(*) c FROM `publicdata.samples.shakespeare`)
```

---

As subselects are not supported inside the SELECT clause, I would use a CROSS JOIN for this specific query:

```
SELECT a.c - b.c
FROM
  (SELECT COUNT(*) c FROM [publicdata:samples.natality]) a
CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT COUNT(*) c FROM [publicdata:samples.shakespeare]) b
```

Comment: This is what I wound up doing, but it looks much uglier than the MySQL way. Are there any plans to support the MySQL way in the future?

Comment: Your votes are our plans :) https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/list?can=2&q=label%3DFeature-Request